# How to sort classes into different packages from default package created by wsdl2java?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, unmarshalling, wsdl2java

I created a classes using apache cxf based on wsdl. When generating classes (wsdl2java -impl -p com.comp.wserv) all generated classes are placed in a single package.
Later, in Eclipse, I am writing the logic  and trying to sort classes into packages. All classes are normally carried in packages with refactoring, except classes that are input objects in the methods (eg, GetPersonByFIO  in com.comp.wserv.GetClientByIdResponse getClient (GetPersonByName parameter)), which are responsible for the return of results.
Can anyone explain to me what the problem is and how to move those classes into not default package, generated by com.comp.wserv?

When you call the service with alraedy moved classes, an error occurs:

in soup ui:

```
<faultstring><![CDATA[Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element
(uri:"http://new.webservice.namespace", local:"requestHead"). Expected
elements are
<{}birthday>,<{}name>,<{}surname>,<{}patronymicName>]]></faultstring>
```

in eclipse console:

```
 05.02.2015 11:16:30.247 WARN  PhaseInterceptorChain:439 - Interceptor for
 {http://new.webservice.namespace}Service#{http://new.webservice.namespace}
 getClient has thrown exception, unwinding now
 org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected
 element (uri:"http://new.webservice.namespace", local:"requestHead").
 Expected elements are
 <{}birthday>,<{}name>,<{}surname>,<{}patronymicName>
```

When classes are in default package - com.comp.wserv - everything ok.

Comment: I still need help... =) So the question is: have anybody problem like "Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element" after move "parameter" object from package which generated as default package by wsdl2java?

Comment: It seems  that the elements (classes) from one namespace must be in one package.